# Integer only if-else condition in php

Tags: php, if-statement, integer

I can't do the integers only for contact number

```
    if($Contactno=="")
{
    $error['Contactno']="Contactno Is Required.";
}
else
{ 
    if( !preg_match("/^([1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i", $Contactno)) 
        $valid_Contactno=$Contactno;
    }
    else
    {
                    $error['Contactno']="Numbers only.";
    }
```

Comment: I have.........no........idea...what........you're........asking.

Comment: in my form there is a field that allows a contact number to input letter. But how can i allow to input numbers only

Comment: that's the code for my if else condition for contact number

Comment: I want that if they input letters it alert that it must be numbers only

Comment: I believe Shankar [`answered`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21827862/) your question @user3276053

Comment: is this correct?
   if($Contactno=="")
 {
  $error['Contactno']="Contactno Is Required."; 
 }
 else
 {
  if(!preg_match("/[0-9]$/", $Contactno))
  {
  $valid_Contactno=$Contactno;
  }
  else
  {
  $error['Contactno']="Numbers only.";
  }
 }
}

Comment: Why not try the solution that Shankar Damodaran provided? It does not seem that you've acknowledged it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the [`ctype_digit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) for checking for numbers instead.

```
if(ctype_digit($Contactno))
 {
   echo "This is a valid contact number !";
 }
else
 {
   echo "You cannot enter characters other than number";
 }
```